# Should "Working set peak" of Perfmon report be plotted in charts/graphs

Tags: performance-testing, perfmon

I have recently started using Perfmon and hence don't have much info on it.

I have a perfmon report which has "Working set" as well as "Peak Working Set" values for different processes. I want to plot a chart/graph which would indicate how much memory (RAM) is consumed by each process during a certain time period. So, what would be the best to use, "Working set" or "Peak Working Set"?

Answer (score 0):

Because you sample these metrics at certain interval such at every milliseconds, therefore "Working set"    will give the RAM usage at these points whereas "Peak Working Set" will give peak RAM usage between two samples. The "Peak Working Set" gives better picture compared to "working set" of memory usage requirement.